# thymeleaf pattern dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: html, date, thymeleaf

I try to validate an input date to have format dd/MM/yyyy like that :

```
<input type="date" th:pattern="${date_format}" th:field="*{subscriptionDate}"/>
```

In my controller, I add an attribute to my model like that :

```
model.addAttribute("date_format", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

But when I submit my form I have this message from my input tag :

> Please respect the format

Comment: The pattern attribute expects a regular expression, by the way https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by updating my model attribute like that :

model.addAttribute("date_format", "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}");